# Need clarification on how to correctly call wp_mail()

Tags: wp-mail

I want to call `wp_mail()` from a non-template PHP file, but when I do, it fails and I don't understand why. For example, let's say I have a PHP file that consists of only this:

```
<?php
    echo 'hi';
    $mail_sent = wp_mail('example@example.com', 'subject', 'message');
    echo $mail_sent;
?>
```

If I load that PHP file directly in my browser, only "hi" will print. If I remove `echo 'hi';` altogether, nothing is printed, which indicates to me that `wp_mail()` cannot be called in this particular context. However, if I add `/* Template Name: SomeName */` to the file and create a new page using `SomeName` as its template, `wp_mail()` executes correctly. Clearly, I'm missing some key bit of information regarding how to correctly call `wp_mail()`.

The reason I want to do this is because the theme I'm using came with a contact form that submits email via an ajax request roughly like this:

```
form.submit(function() {
    $j.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/themeX/send_mail.php",
        data: form.serialize(),
    });
});
```

Currently, `send_mail.php` calls the PHP `mail()` function which "works" but is extremely flaky. I want it to call `wp_mail()` so I can take advantage of [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/) which sends mail using a SMTP server. So my question is: how can I get `wp_mail()` to work in this situation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standalone script will not load WordPress, so it doesn't have a `wp_mail()` function. WordPress has its own built-in Ajax handlers which you can leverage and have access to all WordPress functionality within those Ajax calls.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Just in case any other wordpress noobs encounter a similar issue, I found this article very helpful: http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/18/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, include the Wordpress functions in your standalone script as follows

```
require_once('wp-blog-header.php');
```

I find the WP ajax functions are not always the best way to do things, so writing your own AJAX handler is quite valid.

Answer (score 0):

wp_mail is a [Pluggable Function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions) so you should be able to call wp-includes/pluggable.php and then have the ablilty to use wp_mail().